# Rank of linear operator involving integral and inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am studying for my exam in Functional Analysis but I'm confused about the following example:

Consider $\mathcal{C}([-\pi,\pi],\mathbb{K})$ with the $\infty$-norm and define $T:X \to X$ by
$$Tf(x)=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} sin(x-y)f(y) dy$$

T has rank 2

I am confused about how to find out that T has rank 2. I only have experience with how to find the rank with matrices. Can you also find the rank when you consider an inner product for example? For example:

[image]

Has finite rank

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\sin(x - y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) - \sin(y) \cos (x)$, so that
\begin{align}
Tf(x) &= \int (\sin(x) \cos(y) - \sin(y) \cos (x)) f(y) dy \\&= \sin(x) \left[\int \cos(y) f(y) dy \right] - \cos(x) \left[ \int \sin(y) f(y) dy \right]
\end{align}The things in square brackets are just numbers, so $Tf$ is always a linear combination of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. They form a subspace of dimension 2, so that the operator $T$ will have rank 2.

Comment: How would you find the rank of  the following operator?
$Tx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \lambda_n <x,e_n>e_n$

Comment: If $\{e_n\}$ is meant to be a(n orthonormal) basis then the range is not finite-dimensional. Note that $Te_n = \lambda_n e_n$, so that $e_n \in \mathrm{ran}(T)$, provided that $\lambda_n \neq 0$. So as long as there are infinitely many $\lambda_n$ that are different from zero, the range will not be finite-dimensional.

Comment: My book says that it has finite rank. Does it have something to do with the given fact (in the book) that $(\lambda_n)$ is a bounded sequence?

Comment: It's definitely not finite rank. Maybe make a separate post for this though, since it's off topic.

Comment: I edited this post (also I made a mistake in the comment above, it must be the sum from n=1 to k, that makes the difference I guess. But I still don't know how to compute the rank here

Comment: If the sum is finite then obviously $T_kx \in \mathrm{span}\{e_1 , \dots , e_k \},$ which is a finite-dimensional subspace. So, the operator has finite rank. However, the sum up to infinity is not finite-rank.

Comment: To be clear, the rank would be $k$ (the number of linearly independent vectors which form a basis of the range).